# How to include tags in terraform when using modules and count

Tags: terraform, google-compute-engine, provisioning, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure

I have to provision many instances using modules and count in it. The issue is , the required tags for some particular instances have to be different. Can any suggest a better way where a tag can be added along with default tags with all instances. Im using a map with all 30 occurrence which is long.

Default tags:tag1,tag2

Example Case:

```
instance1......instance15     -       tag1,tag2

instance16                    -       tag1,tag2,tag_xxx

instance17......instance29    -       tag1,tag2.

instance30                    -       tag1,tag2,tag_yyy
```

Terraform Code:

```
module "compute-vm" {
  count         = length(var.names)
  source        = "../modules/compute-vm"
  project_id    = var.project_id
  name          = var.name[count.index]
  tags          = var.tags[var.names[count.index]]

variable "tags" {
  type        = map(list(string))
}


tags.tfvars:

tags= {
    "instance1" = ["tag1","tag2"],
    "instance2"=["tag1","tag2"],
    "instance3" = ["tag1","tag2"],
.
.
.
.

    "instance16"=["tag1","tag2",tag_xxx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two lists with [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html).
Something along the lines of:

```
variable "default_tags" {
  type = list(string)
}

module "compute-vm" {
  ...
  tags = concat(var.default_tags, var.tags[var.names[count.index]])
}
```

---

Additionally, I would use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) instead of `count`. Which makes the block easier to read. Additionally you can later refer to the block via `module.compute-vm["instance1"]` instead of having to do it with indices `module.compute-vm[0]`. Because who knows if the first VM is really `"instance1"` (maybe Terraform changes the order inside the map).

```
module "compute-vm" {
  for_each   = var.tags
  source     = "../modules/compute-vm"
  project_id = var.project_id
  name       = each.key
  tags       = each.value  // or concat(var.default_tags, each.value)
}
```